# After switch to PixateFreestyle, some styles not apply on load

Tags: css, ios7, pixate

I switch (with CoccoaPods) from Pixate to PixateFreestyle. I make not change in my code or the style.

Now this style is not applied:

```
.posTable {
  background-color: #003366;
  separator-color: #003366;
}
.posTable table-view-cell {
  background-color: #001933;
}
```

However, if I re-save the CSS (using the live CSS) it get applied. Because the only change was move to PixateFreestyle, I don't know that to do (apart to switch back).

Comment: Did you add the [PixateFreestyle initializePixateFreestyle]; in your main.m?

Comment: Is this on device or in simulator? I just tried your CSS and it worked fine, both first time and after making live changes.

Comment: @pixatepaul Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a workaround.

The issue is the order to set the values. If is set:

```
self.documentItemsTable.dataSource = self.documentItemsTable;
self.documentItemsTable.delegate = self.documentItemsTable;
self.documentItemsTable.styleClass = @"posTable";
```

It fails. However if set:

```
self.documentItemsTable.styleClass = @"posTable";
self.documentItemsTable.delegate = self.documentItemsTable;
```

It work. In fact, if the delegate is not set it not work, or if set before the styleClass.